# Python/GTK3: How to keep a window open on destroy?

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, gtk3

I'm trying to **forbid** the user **to close the GTK Window**.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

def on_destroy(evt):
    print("Please don't close me") # <- works
    return False                   # <- doesn't work, the window closes
    # return True                  # <- same behaviour as False

win = Gtk.Window()
win.connect('destroy', on_destroy)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

The event is triggered, but I don't know how to interrupt it. Is `destroy` maybe too late and I need something like `before_destroy`?

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Try *Returning `True` to stop event propagation*

Comment: @stovfl Thanks, but it's the same behaviour.

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev Thanks, that's what I was looking for. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it. :-)